# Prevent redirection from the browser bar

Tags: c#, asp.net

Running an aspx page

```
http://localhost:30894/StaffPanel.aspx
```

Whenever I run my project. I realized that a user can actually just changed the page name to get to another page like

```
http://localhost:30894/AdminPanel.aspx
```

How will I be able to prevent the user from being redirected?

Comment: You need to write code in code behind to check If the user is logged in and what role user belongs to and show error or redirect to proper page if criteria is not followed. You need to understand authorization in asp.net to be able to implement this better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not.

In other hand, you should have some user system with login and special roles. Then if user is not logged in or does not have special admin role, you show him access restricted message.

**WORKAROUND, NOT RECOMMENDED**: And if you need to do it fast, you can add just special parameter, like key, `http://localhost:30894/AdminPanel.aspx?key=somesecrectpass` to be able to access page.

Comment: I do have a log in.. but even so, when logged on, i can still change the bar address

Comment: @Mau it will be always possible to change bar address. You have to check in AdminPanel.aspx if that user can use that page.